# cmake link with libboost_python-py32.so instead of libboost_python.so

Tags: c++, python, boost, cmake

I'm trying to build python bindings for a library that i wrote, and i'm having some trouble getting cmake to understand that it should use the boost-python library for python 3.

Here is my cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

FIND_PACKAGE(Boost COMPONENTS
                system
                thread
                python REQUIRED)
find_package(PythonLibs REQUIRED)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

ADD_LIBRARY(
  pschulze SHARED
  src/candidate_relation.cpp
  src/schulze.cpp
  src/calculate.cpp
  src/candidate.cpp
  src/ranking.cpp
  src/userinput.cpp
  python.cpp)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(pschulze ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})

ADD_EXECUTABLE(
  schulze
  src/candidate_relation.cpp
  src/schulze.cpp
  src/calculate.cpp
  src/candidate.cpp
  src/ranking.cpp
  src/userinput.cpp
  src/json-spirit/json_spirit_reader.cpp
  src/json-spirit/json_spirit_value.cpp
  main.cpp)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(schulze ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})

ADD_DEFINITIONS(-std=gnu++0x -Os)

add_subdirectory (tests)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
```

And this is the linker error that I get:

```
Linking CXX executable schulze
CMakeFiles/schulze.dir/src/schulze.cpp.o: In function `arg_to_python':
/usr/include/boost/python/converter/builtin_converters.hpp:122: undefined reference to `PyInt_FromLong'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../lib/libboost_python.so: undefined reference to `PyString_Size'
```

Comment: Does changing to `find_package(PythonLibs 3 REQUIRED)` work?  You should probably delete your CMakeCache.txt before trying.

Comment: the builtin_converters.hpp:122 error disappeared, but the libboost_python.so: undefined reference to `PyString_Size' is still there.

Comment: @Fraser: `find_package(PythonLibs 3 REQUIRED)` won't help you to find the corresponding Boost.Python library. It finds the Python "basic" language libraries only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might do the trick :

```
set(Python_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS 3.2)

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system thread python-py32 REQUIRED)
```

Comment: This may work e.g. on Ubuntu. But if you compile Boost from sources on the Mac, the library is called simply `libboost_python3`. May happen on other Linux distributions (e.g. Fedora) as well.

Comment: @user465139 where would you set that?